# How to extract the text from the HTML string and integrate back to the HTML string?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

In my application I let the user edit the text shown in the `UIWebView` if edit option clicked
I used below method to extract the text shown in the webview.

```
NSString *htmlString=@"<p style="letter-spacing:0px;color:#3485BD;font-size:24pt;font-family:Arial;text-anchor:start;text-align:start;" id="textArea_1">Enter Your Question</p>";
NSCharacterSet *set=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"><"];
NSArray *arr1=[htmlString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
```

below is the result of the above code snippet

```
(
    "",
    "p style=\"letter-spacing:0px;color:#3485BD;font-size:24pt;font-family:Arial;text-anchor:start;text-align:start;\" id=\"textArea_1\"",
    "Enter Your Question",
    "/p",
    ""
)
```

The required text is at index 2 I show it in an UITextField for the user to edit But I don't know how to integrate that edited text into the HTML string

Because I disintegrate using NSCharacterSet object containing chars > and < `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` but it is not possible to integrate. Help me if there is some other way?

Comment: `[result objectAtIndex:2]` will return you "Enter Your Question".

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I corrected my question now

Comment: <in hindi> tum chahte ho ki "Enter you Question" ko edit karne ke baad jo text ho wo HTML string me replace ho jaye? <English translation> you want the edited text to act as a replacement for "Enter you Question"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yes I want edited text to replace "Enter you Question"

Comment: I think simple... you must have heard `swap`.... same thing

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  I am really either I am not aware of that or I have used it a very long before to forget, so direct me to link or something

Comment: swap two values... simply yaar.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You mean  replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:newText

Comment: @AnoopVaidya After replacing I can't combine it into a HTML string

Comment: then try to replace from `htmlString` only...